# Camel FTPs FileNotFoundException with keystore file in resources of war

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, ftps, camel-ftp

I've trying to connect my Spring Boot application to FTPs server via camel-ftp.
And I configured keystore file by `ftpClient.trustStore.file` parameter in  FTPs Connection Uri.
It's work as normal with running debug in IDE but when packaging application to war file and deploy in Docker container. I got FileNotFoundException : `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/usr/app/app.war!/WEB-INF/classes!/keys/diode.jks (No such file or directory)`

I've tried to check

1. Extra war file and keystore already existed in /classes/keys folder (it be coppied from /resources/keys folder in source code)
2. Add log and I can get content of keystore file when running application with war but can not get file path to pass to FTPs connection Uri.

How can I get real file keystore file path in war and pass to ftpClient.trustStore.file parameter in FTPs connection Uri with camel-ftp

Answer (score 0):

From the exception message, I would infer that something is trying to open a "file:" URL as if it was a regular file pathname.  That won't work.

1. If you have something that needs a file path you need to give it a real file path.  Not a `file:` URL.
2. If a URL refers to a resource *inside* a JAR or WAR file, there is no valid filesystem path for it.  Stuff inside an archive file cannot be opened that way.  Your operating system's "open file" syscalls require a pathname not a URL.

So what you are probably going to have to do is to *extract* the keystore file from the WAR and write it to a file in the file system.  (It sounds like this has already been done.)  Then you need to change the FTPS connection URL to use the pathname of that file file.

Comment: Yes, If I store keystore in file system of server and use absolute path. It's work as expect. But I want to store keystore inside war file for dynamic deployment to help bring it to deploy to any server without copy keystore file to new server

Comment: You might want to, but you can't.  If the keystore is ONLY inside the the WAR file, then your application needs to extract the (by reading in as a resource) and then write that file to the file system.  Then it uses the pathname of the file in the file system.  (It makes very little difference from the security perspective.  If a hacker can read files in the file system they can also read the WAR file and extract the keystore for themselves.)

Comment: (I say you can't ... but what I mean is that you can't without modifying Camel-ftp to work differently.)

Comment: yeah, I know. I've tried to use same way as your suggestion. Use code to read keystore as resource and write to file system at first running of application. It's ok for deployment to anywhere without manual copy keystore to each server. I asked this question to want to know have any other way to help resolve this issue :), Thanks Stephen !